# Formulas for Pythagorean triples using Jacobsthal numbers and other well-known sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Given Fibonacci numbers $F_n$, we have the known,

$$(F_n F_{n+3})^2+(2F_{n+1}F_{n+2})^2 = (F_{2n+3})^2$$

as well as Lucas numbers $L_n$,

$$(L_n L_{n+3})^2+(2L_{n+1}L_{n+2})^2 = (L_{2n+2}+L_{2n+4})^2$$

and made me wonder if other sequences obey similar relationships.

---

**Q:** Are there similar formulas for Pythagorean triples using the *[Jacobsthal numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobsthalNumber.html)*,

$$J_n =  0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 11, 21, 43, 85, \dots$$

*Jacobsthal-Lucas numbers*,

$$K_n = 2, 1, 5, 7, 17, 31, 65, 127, \dots$$

*[Padovan sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence)*,

$$P_n = 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12,  \dots$$

*[Perrin numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perrin_number)*,

$$Q_n = 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 7, 10, 12, 17, \dots$$

or other well-known sequences?

---

**P.S.** Of course, we $\color{red}{\text{disregard}}$ the obvious,

$$(J_m^2-J_n^2)^2+(2J_mJ_n)^2 = (J_m^2+J_n^2)^2$$

Comment: How about using general formula of each sequence? For example, we have $F_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\phi^{n}+\phi^{-n})$ where $\phi = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$.

Comment: @See-WooLee: It's not that easy. The first formula alone uses 5 different Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Adjacent [Pell numbers](https://oeis.org/A000129) can be use to generate triples where $B=A\pm1\quad (m,n)\in\{0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, 408, 985, ...\}$